# Vacuum Tube Furnace Sealing Flange Design

Tags: semiconductor-physics, vacuum

I know this is not the best place to post this question, but in an effort to get the most prompt and direct response I chose this forum.

Can anyone suggest a good reference to the design parameters and guidelines, drawings or 3D models of a vacuum tube furnace sealing flange?

Comment: Depends a bunch on the required performance of the vacuum tube furnace. MilliTorr vacuum might just be an o-ring compressed around the OD of the tube, UHV will require a glass-to-metal seal and Conflat flanges.

Comment: I am building an induction tube furnace (114mm OD, 6.35mm thick borosilicate) for infusion of molten material into a fiber materials matrix; therefore, the only structure exposed to high heat will be the crucible and its content. A mTorr vacuum seems like it should do the trick, but I will see once I do a few experiments. I definitely want to stay away from conflat flanges if I can, but I may need to revisit if the initial experiments do not yield a good result.

Comment: Either might well work. My next question will be just how hot you expect the tube to get. This might drive o-ring choice, or you may need active cooling at the ends of the tube. Years ago I had a 50mm tube under "house" vacuum using an external quartz-halogen lamp to heat samples to 700C or so. The hot zone was about 150mm in the center of a 600mm tube. The ends were cool enough to use Viton o-rings in standard brass compression fittings.

Comment: Since the induction coil will have water running through it, I do not see the ends of the tube with the o-rings getting too hot; however, I will use Viton to be safe.

Comment: "A mTorr vacuum seems like it should do the trick...", "... will have water running through..." -- it would be nice if you would _edit your question_ with this and other relevant information.  It's a StackExchange thing; we're different from other fora.